# Android spinner adapter selecting doesn't work with using custom BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, spinner, adapter, baseadapter

I have a problem with my custom adapter for spinner element. Spinner shows a list from my adapter but when I try to select item it doesnt work.

Here is my code of adapter:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private final ArrayList<String> categories;
    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList catList){
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        categories = catList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categories.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return categories.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textView.setText(getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: define: *but when I try to select item it doesnt work* in the question

Comment: @Selvin, when I run my app spinner doesn't have selected any item, when I try choose one from the spinner list select nothing changes. When I try method spinner.getSelected() it returns null.

Comment: `getSelected()` spinner has no such method also your adapter implementation look generally ok ... so problem is not with this code ...

Answer (score 0):

if you want any item preselected when spinner appears over screen, you can use

```
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

and if you want to get position of any item then use below code,

```
position = arrayList.indexOf("your item");
```

menual way,

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            spinner.setSelection(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```